# Need a way to have thread pool of Perl LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

Basically I am writing a script where I need to send HTTP request and based on response again more request can be send to the server and will perform the operation. To achieve the same we have a written a small sub-routine which can return [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) below is the code for it.

```
sub createLWPUAObject
{
    $logger->info(
                 "Entered createLWPUAObject() - Creating LWP UserAgent Object");
    my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $userAgent->timeout($httpRequestTimeout);
    $userAgent->env_proxy;
    $logger->info("Exiting createLWPUAObject() - Returning User agent Object");
    return $userAgent;
}
```

Now the design of the script is such that we have multiple level of thread which in terms can spawn worker thread if some work is returned as part of initial threads. Due to this as these threads can also create LWP::UserAgent sometime I observed that the web server host return 500 as response. When we check the host when such error was being reported it was observed that most of the sockets were in TIME_WAIT due to which we are not able to establish further connections.

One of the solution I came up that when the worker thread is launched we pass only one LWP::UserAgent which will be used by that thread for its entire lifetime but still as the parent threads are getting spawned at higher rates we are getting errors.

So how we can make a pool of LWP::UserAgent so that I can limit the connections and also make sure that we have the socket in Established mode till the script run.
Please note that script can take 6-7 hours so we need to make sure that the sockets need to be in Established mode for that period.

Comment: After looking further I found LWP::ConnCache which provides a connection caching mechanism as per the Perl Doc 
**use LWP::ConnCache;
$browser->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new()): This tells the browser object to try using the HTTP/1.1 "Keep-Alive" feature, which speeds up requests by reusing the same socket connection for multiple requests to the same server.**
So I have update my code as below
    `my $cache = LWP::ConnCache->new;
    my $num_connections = 100;
    $cache->total_capacity([$num_connections]);
    $userAgent->conn_cache($cache);`
So is this a correct way for achiving pool.

Answer (score 1):

Seems using the LWP::ConnCache help in make the connection closing in a graceful mechanism. As previously we were using LWP::UserAgent which terminate the connection somewhat in ungraceful format.
Below is the code which help us in a form to have a connection pool and reusing the same connection.

```
sub createLWPUAObject
{
    $logger->info(
                 "Entered createLWPUAObject() - Creating LWP UserAgent Object");
    my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $userAgent->timeout($httpRequestTimeout);
$cache = LWP::ConnCache->new; my $num_connections = 100; 
$cache->total_capacity([$num_connections]); 
$userAgent->conn_cache($cache);
return $userAgent;
}
```

Also with minor tweaking we can make the connection limit to be constant across threads.